# Is multisite a good option?

Tags: multi-sites

I am a single developer making a good few sites in drupal.  At the moment I have one site working, I will be using the same modules for the next few but different theming.  Is multisite a good option even though wont be sharing any content?  I just want to be able to manage the sites on the one laptop, the one installation if possible & save time downloading modules again and again.  All of the sites will have different domains, none of them subsites.  I have been trying to get this working for weeks but am in an awful fuzzle now.  Any thoughts?  I tried to post on drupal.org forums but couldnt even get that working.  Any help welcome..

Regards
Naoimi

Comment: All subsites of mu previous employer was in multisite setup and we migrated away from it. But our reasons was not technical ones, they were management ones. Some things got harder, some got easier, worked all right either way. And we are talking about thousands visits a day, sometimes way more, so it was thoroughly tested ;)

Comment: Thanks for this input... exactly what I was swaying towards...

Comment: Hello, and welcome. Since you found aburke626's answer appropriate, you should ACCEPT it by clicking on the checkmark. This will prevent this question from appearing in the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want multisite. If you're concerned about environment spinup time, create a [drush make](http://drush.ws/docs/make.txt) file with the modules and settings you want. You can even [generate one online.](http://drushmake.me/)

You could also use a development environment like Pantheon or Kalabox or Acquia Dev Desktop, or another distribution to get started.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for for weeks... So thank you very much... think found my new forum... thanks so much....